# I couldnt draw a graph using Json Value in Php

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("chart", $con); 
// The Chart table contains two fields: weekly_task and percentage
// This example will display a pie chart. If you need other charts such as a Bar chart, you will need to modify the code a little to make it work with bar chart and other charts
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM googlechart");

/*
---------------------------
example data: Table (Chart)
--------------------------
weekly_task     percentage
Sleep           30
Watching Movie  40
work            44
*/

$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
   if(!isset($google_JSON)){    
     $google_JSON = "{cols: [";    
     $column = array_keys($r);
     foreach($column as $key=>$value){
         $google_JSON_cols[]="label: '".$value."'}";
     }    
     $google_JSON .= implode(",",$google_JSON_cols)."],rows: [";       
   }
   $google_JSON_rows[] = " {c: ".$r['weekly_task']."} , {v: ".$r['percentage']."}  ]}";
}    
// you may need to change the above into a function that loops through rows, with $r['id'] etc, referring to the fields you want to inject..
echo $google_JSON.implode(",",$google_JSON_rows)."]}";
?>

 <html>
      <head>
        <!--Load the Ajax API-->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

             var jsonData = $.ajax({
                dataType:"json",
                url: "data.php",
                async: false
                }).responseText;

                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                dataType:"json",
                url: "data.php",
                async: false
                }).responseText;


          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
          var options = {
               title: 'My Weekly Plan',
              is3D: 'true',
              width: 800,
              height: 600
            };
          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          // Do not forget to check your div ID
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Output

```
{cols: [label: 'weekly_task'},label: 'percentage'}],rows: [ {c: Sleep} , {v: 30} ]}, {c: Watching_Movie} , {v: 10} ]}, {c: job} , {v: 40} ]}, {c: Exercise} , {v: 20} ]}]}
```

Only this is displayed,No Graph.

Comment: JSON produced is not valid

Comment: Use PHP's built-in `json_encode()` rather than constructing the JSON yourself.

Comment: Pekka: Instead what I should use json_encode()?

Comment: $myJson = json_encode($google_JSON_rows);

echo $myJson;    Still I doesnt Work

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).